# How can I run loops over two lists with two vectors in r?

Tags: r, loops

I have two lists (`lp` and `lpara`) with 12000 dataframes (same names: numbers from 1 to 12000). Each dataframe has a column with months from 1 to 12, the lengths are different: `lp` has 468 and `lpara` 12 rows. I want to run the code over the 12 month for each dataframe from the lists and write the result in a list.

First, I wrote a code for one sample of lists (`lp [[79]]` and `lpara[[79]]`). The following code worked:

```
    results <- data.frame(matrix(vector(), nrow = 12, ncol= 5,dimnames=list(c(), 
                     c("longitude", "latitude", "time", "A", "p.value"))),
                     stringsAsFactors=F)
    #Loop over 12 months for AD
    for(i in 1:12){
      P <- subset(lp[[79]], month == month[i], select = P)
      P <- P[,1]
      sh <- as.numeric(subset(lpara[[79]], time == time[i], select = shape))
      sc <- as.numeric(subset(lpara[[79]], time == time[i], select = scale))
      AD <- ad.test(P, "pgamma", shape= sh, rate = sc)
      results$A[i]<- AD[[1]]
      results$p.value[i] <- AD[[2]]
      
      results$longitude <- lpara[[79]][,1]
      results$latitude <- lpara[[79]][,2]
      results$time <- as.numeric(c(1:12))
    }
```

Now I want to run the loop over more than on sample of list and wrote a second loop:

```
    results <- lapply(seq_len(12000), function(x, nr = 12, nc = 5) {data.frame(matrix(,nrow=nr,      ncol=nc, dimnames=list(c(), c("longitude", "latitude", "time", "A", "p.value")))) })
    #Loop over 12000 Grids
    for(j in 1:12000){
    #Loop over 12 months for AD
    for(i in 1:12){
    P <- subset(lp[[j]], month == month[i], select = P)
    P <- P[,1]
    sh <- as.numeric(subset(lpara[[j]], time == time[i], select = shape))
    sc <- as.numeric(subset(lpara[[j]], time == time[i], select = scale))
    AD <- ad.test(P, "pgamma", shape= sh, rate = sc)
    
    results[[j]]$A[i]<- AD[[1]]
    results[[j]]$p.value[i] <- AD[[2]]
    
    results[[j]]$longitude <- lpara[[j]][,1]
    results[[j]]$latitude <- lpara[[j]][,2]
    results[[j]]$time <- as.numeric(c(1:12))
    }
    }
```

This doesn't work and I don't know why. Maybe someone can help me? That would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the elementwise loop member of *apply* family, `mapply` (or its wrapper `Map`), with an underlying `lapply` (replacing `for`) for data frame build. You can also use `tryCatch` to account for exceptions without stopping code run.

```
proc_adresults <- function(lp_df, lpara_df){    
   # BUILD LIST OF DATA FRAMES
   df_list <- lapply(1:12, function(i) {
      tryCatch({
          P  <- subset(lp_df, month == month[i])$P         # RETURN VECTOR FROM COL PICK 
          sh <- subset(lpara_df, time == time[i])$shape    # RETURN VECTOR FROM COL PICK
          sc <- subset(lpara_df, time == time[i])$scale    # RETURN VECTOR FROM COL PICk

          AD <- ad.test(P, "pgamma", shape= sh, rate = sc)

          data.frame(A = AD[[1]],                          # USE OBJ NAME AND NOT NUMBER
                     p.value   = AD[[2]],                  # USE OBJ NAME AND NOT NUMBER
                     longitude = lpara_df[,1][1],          # USE COL NAME AND NOT NUMBER
                     latitude  = lpara_df[,2][1],          # USE COL NAME AND NOT NUMBER
                     time = i,
                     error = NA)
      }, error = function(e)
           data.frame(A = NA, p.value = NA, 
                      longitude = lpara_df[,1][1], 
                      latitude  = lpara_df[,2][1],
                      time = i, error = as.character(e))  
      )  
   })

   # CONCATENATE ALL 12 ONE-ROW DFs INTO SINGLE DF
   do.call(rbind, df_list)
}

# EQUIVALENT CALLS
adresults_df_list <- Map(proc_adresults, lp, lpara)
adresults_df_list <- mapply(proc_adresults, lp, lpara, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Alternatively, consider `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) after a `merge` and avoid the `subset` calls. Same above `Map`/`mapply` calls.

```
proc_adresults <- function(lp_df, lpara_df){ 
   # MERGE TO DATA FRAMES BY MONTH
   mdf <- merge(lp_df, lpara_df, by.x="month", by.y="time")

   # BUILD LIST OF DATA FRAMES
   df_list <- by(mdf, mdf$month, function(sub) {    
      tryCatch({
          AD <- ad.test(sub$P, "pgamma", shape= sub$sh[1], rate = sub$sc[1])

          data.frame(A = AD$statistic,
                     p.value   = AD$pv.value,
                     longitude = sub$longitude[1],
                     latitude  = sub$latitude[1],
                     time = sub$time[1],
                     error = NA)
      }, error = function(e)
           data.frame(A = NA, p.value = NA, 
                      longitude = sub$longitude[1], 
                      latitude  = sub$latitude[1],
                      time = sub$time[1], error = as.character(e))  
      )  
   })

   # CONCATENATE ALL 12 ONE-ROW DFs INTO SINGLE DF
   do.call(rbind, df_list)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks better than my version. Unfortunately the code is not running yet. I get the error message "Error in if (any(U < 0 | U > 1)) stop("null distribution function returned values outside [0,1]") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed ". I think this is because some dataframes only contain NAs in the P column. Unfortunately, it then stops completely, instead of taking the dataframes where it should work.  Do you know a way how he writes NAs in the output in that case?

Comment: See update using `tryCatch` which you can capture exceptions without code disruption, even return empty row data frames and its errors in a new column.

Comment: Thank you again. Now there is a new error message:  "Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("simpleError", "error", "condition")’ to a data.frame"
This time I don't know where it came from. I tried to find it on the Internet, but found nothing. Have you ever read something like this and know where the error can come from?

Comment: Whoops! You need to cast the error message to character: `as.character(e)`. See edit.

Comment: Perfect, that works! Thank you very much. Where can I learn to program like you?

Comment: Great to hear!  Curious, which version did you use `Map` + `lapply` or `Map` + `by`? Practice, practice, practice is my advice. Even come back to SO and start *answering* questions!

Comment: I used the Map + lapply, this one is more logical for me. I think I still have to ask some questions here, before I can answer some :D But hopefully one day...